# use string.translate in Python to transliterate Cyrillic?

Tags: python, transliteration

I'm getting `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-51: ordinal not in range(128)` exception trying to use `string.maketrans` in `Python`. I'm kinda discouraged with this kind of error in following code ([gist](https://gist.github.com/4462092)):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import string

def translit1(string):
    """ This function works just fine """
    capital_letters = {
        u'А': u'A',
        u'Б': u'B',
        u'В': u'V',
        u'Г': u'G',
        u'Д': u'D',
        u'Е': u'E',
        u'Ё': u'E',
        u'Ж': u'Zh',
        u'З': u'Z',
        u'И': u'I',
        u'Й': u'Y',
        u'К': u'K',
        u'Л': u'L',
        u'М': u'M',
        u'Н': u'N',
        u'О': u'O',
        u'П': u'P',
        u'Р': u'R',
        u'С': u'S',
        u'Т': u'T',
        u'У': u'U',
        u'Ф': u'F',
        u'Х': u'H',
        u'Ц': u'Ts',
        u'Ч': u'Ch',
        u'Ш': u'Sh',
        u'Щ': u'Sch',
        u'Ъ': u'',
        u'Ы': u'Y',
        u'Ь': u'',
        u'Э': u'E',
        u'Ю': u'Yu',
        u'Я': u'Ya'
    }

    lower_case_letters = {
        u'а': u'a',
        u'б': u'b',
        u'в': u'v',
        u'г': u'g',
        u'д': u'd',
        u'е': u'e',
        u'ё': u'e',
        u'ж': u'zh',
        u'з': u'z',
        u'и': u'i',
        u'й': u'y',
        u'к': u'k',
        u'л': u'l',
        u'м': u'm',
        u'н': u'n',
        u'о': u'o',
        u'п': u'p',
        u'р': u'r',
        u'с': u's',
        u'т': u't',
        u'у': u'u',
        u'ф': u'f',
        u'х': u'h',
        u'ц': u'ts',
        u'ч': u'ch',
        u'ш': u'sh',
        u'щ': u'sch',
        u'ъ': u'',
        u'ы': u'y',
        u'ь': u'',
        u'э': u'e',
        u'ю': u'yu',
        u'я': u'ya'
    }

    translit_string = ""

    for index, char in enumerate(string):
        if char in lower_case_letters.keys():
            char = lower_case_letters[char]
        elif char in capital_letters.keys():
            char = capital_letters[char]
            if len(string) > index+1:
                if string[index+1] not in lower_case_letters.keys():
                    char = char.upper()
            else:
                char = char.upper()
        translit_string += char

    return translit_string


def translit2(text):
    """ This method should be more easy to grasp, 
    but throws exception:
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-51: ordinal not in range(128)
    """

    symbols = string.maketrans(u"абвгдеёзийклмнопрстуфхъыьэАБВГДЕЁЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЪЫЬЭ",
                               u"abvgdeezijklmnoprstufh'y'eABVGDEEZIJKLMNOPRSTUFH'Y'E")
    sequence = {
        u'ж':'zh',
        u'ц':'ts',
        u'ч':'ch',
        u'ш':'sh',
        u'щ':'sch',
        u'ю':'ju',
        u'я':'ja',
        u'Ж':'Zh',
        u'Ц':'Ts',
        u'Ч':'Ch'
    }

    for char in sequence.keys():
        text = text.replace(char, sequence[char])

    return text.translate(symbols)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print translit1(u"Привет") # prints Privet as expected
    print translit2(u"Привет") # throws exception: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-51: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Original trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "translit_error.py", line 124, in <module>
    print translit2(u"Привет") # throws exception: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-51: ordinal not in range(128)
  File "translit_error.py", line 103, in translit2
    u"abvgdeezijklmnoprstufh'y'eABVGDEEZIJKLMNOPRSTUFH'Y'E")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-51: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I mean, why Python `string.maketrans` trying to use `ascii` table anyway? And how comes English alphabet letters are out of 0-128 range?

```
$ python -c "print ord(u'A')"
65
$ python -c "print ord(u'z')"
122
$ python -c "print ord(u\"'\")"
39
```

After several hours I feel like absolutely exhausted to solve this issue.

Can someone say what is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? IIRC, Python 2 `maketrans` cannot handle non-ASCII characters. (But Python 3 should be fine.)

Comment: From what I remember, the unicode version of `maketrans` requires you to map unicode characters to ordinals (I don't know why).

Comment: Python 2.7.3 - sorry, I didn't specify it. This is sad it's not in [string.makestrans documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-functions)

Comment: Take a look at the [unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) module. It transliterates pretty well.

Comment: Thank you guys, you saved me a lot of time. @Blender, unfortuantely `unidecode` is not an option for me (explained below in @thg345's answer), though it's handy to use. @kojiro, the code above works fine with python 3 just as you said.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[translate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) behaves differently when used with unicode strings. Instead of a `maketrans` table, you have to provide a dictionary `ord(search)->ord(replace)`:

```
symbols = (u"абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ",
           u"abvgdeejzijklmnoprstufhzcss_y_euaABVGDEEJZIJKLMNOPRSTUFHZCSS_Y_EUA")

tr = {ord(a):ord(b) for a, b in zip(*symbols)}

# for Python 2.*:
# tr = dict( [ (ord(a), ord(b)) for (a, b) in zip(*symbols) ] )

text = u'Добрый Ден'
print text.translate(tr)  # looks good
```

That said, I'd second the suggestion not to reinvent the wheel and to use an established library: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode

Comment: Thanks, this works just fine. But I'm still mad that it's not pointed in the documentation to `string.maketrans` :) Unfortunately `unidecode` handles Cyrillic transliteration pretty ugly when it comes to transliteration of certain symbols in russian. My goal is to make URL slugs for (guess who? google of course) from titles written in russian, so I need make a transliteration of a slug that google would "understand". I tried `unidecode` on one world in russian and fed it to google, - wasn't satisfied with the result - google said "maybe you meant <another word>".

Comment: Some letters were missed, so C-V, C-P approach caused error :) The full russian-alphabet dict version should look like this: `
symbols = (u"абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ",
u"abvgdeejzijklmnoprstufhzcss_y_euaABVGDEEJZIJKLMNOPRSTUFHZCSS_Y_EUA")` .

Comment: @MInner: this is not going to work with translate, because it can only do one to one replacement.

Comment: @thg435 that is one-to-one. Russian letters just seem to be somehow wider :) That wasn't like criticism, but the thing a spent few minutes on - thinking why everything fails with letter "ч" is in the string.

Comment: @MInner: ok, looks I misunderstood your comment. Would you mind editing this info in, so that others with the same problem have an immediate copypaste solution?

Answer (score 34):

You can use transliterate package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/transliterate)

Example #1:

```
from transliterate import translit
print translit("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "ru")
# Лорем ипсум долор сит амет
```

Example #2:

```
print translit(u"Лорем ипсум долор сит амет", "ru", reversed=True)
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Comment: Transliterate 1.7.3 has got some issues with the greek language https://github.com/barseghyanartur/transliterate/issues/8

Answer (score 16):

Check out the [CyrTranslit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cyrtranslit) package, it's specifically made to transliterate from and to Cyrillic script text. It currently supports Serbian, Montenegrin, Macedonian, and Russian.

Example usage:

```
>>> import cyrtranslit
>>> cyrtranslit.supported()
['me', 'sr', 'mk', 'ru']

>>> cyrtranslit.to_latin('Моё судно на воздушной подушке полно угрей', 'ru')
'Moyo sudno na vozdushnoj podushke polno ugrej'

>>> cyrtranslit.to_cyrillic('Moyo sudno na vozdushnoj podushke polno ugrej')
'Моё судно на воздушной подушке полно угрей'
```

Comment: Thank you, I found this very useful.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another short solution with more accurate transliteration:

```py
symbols = (u"абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ ",
    (*list(u'abvgdee'), 'zh', *list(u'zijklmnoprstuf'), 'kh', 'z', 'ch', 'sh', 'sh', '',
    'y', '', 'e', 'yu','ya', *list(u'ABVGDEE'), 'ZH', 
    *list(u'ZIJKLMNOPRSTUF'), 'KH', 'Z', 'CH', 'SH', 'SH', *list(u'_Y_E'), 'YU', 'YA', ' '))

coding_dict = {source: dest for source, dest in zip(*symbols)}
translate = lambda x: ''.join([coding_dict[i] for i in x])

text = u'Добро пожаловать'
translate(text)
# 'Dobro pozhalovat'
```

Comment: It still have an issue, if you have any other character than Cyrillic in name