# English keyboard text to Russian in Python

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm trying to replace a string that contains letters from the English keyboard "gjceljvjtxyfz" to the corresponding Russian "посудомоечная". I am NOT trying to translate or transliterate from English to Russian, but to replace the English letters with the corresponding letters on the Russian keyboard. I haven't found any Python libraries or useful code to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you seek is called **transliteration** and you can check this similar question already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14173421/4636715

Comment: @vahdet no that's not what I'm seeking. I want to replace the letters in the English keyboard with the ones in Russian. For instance: "qwerty" should be replaced with "йцукен"

Comment: @vahdet There is no way that this is transliteration in the ordinary sense. That Russian word could be transliterated something like posudomoyechnaya. It shouldn't be a surprise that there isn't a word Russian pronounced gjceljvjtxyfz...

Comment: Ah ok, sorry for that. Yet, I am not deleting in order not to make the mentioning comments obsolete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate) method. It requires a mapping of integers (character codes) to characters (strings of length 1). You can create this mapping manually, like so:

```
translation = {}
translation[ord('q')] = 'й'
translation[ord('w')] = 'ц'
...
```

and then use it:

```
s1 = "gjceljvjtxyfz"
s2 = s1.translate(translation)
```

If you want to avoid long and inefficient code which creates the `translation` table, you can use [`maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans):

```
translation = str.maketrans(dict(zip('qwerty','йцукен')))
```

The specifics are slightly different for Python 2 and 3; the code sections above are for Python 3.