# mysql detects duplicate but not programming languages

Tags: python, mysql

here in this table https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mU8RhMyiNb6RBjdaYZztci/0

i try to insert two names `girisken, girişken` and for `mysql` this is a duplicate and the second one can not be insert because the first exists and i am fine

but in python when i do

```
a = 'girisken'
b = 'girişken'
print(a == b)
```

it gives me `false` and that makes problems trying to insert it to mysql

how to solve this problem?

my collation is `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` in mysql

Comment: This might be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173421/use-string-translate-in-python-to-transliterate-cyrillic

Answer (score 1):

Character equivalence is based on the collation.

In MySQL's default collation utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, `'s'` is equal to `'ş'`:

```
mysql> select 'girisken' = 'girişken' as same;
+------+
| same |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
```

I infer that this word is from the Türkçe language (I assume since [the country now wants to be known as Türkiye](https://www.cyprusmedianet.com/news/57621/turkey-wants-to-change-its-name/), their language maybe should be known as Türkçe?).

So the proper collation should be chosen for that language:

```
mysql> select 'girisken' = 'girişken' collate utf8mb4_turkish_ci as same;
+------+
| same |
+------+
|    0 |
+------+
```

Or in MySQL 8.0, an updated collation is available:

```
mysql> select 'girisken' = 'girişken' collate utf8mb4_tr_0900_ai_ci as same;
+------+
| same |
+------+
|    0 |
+------+
```

Comment: if i wanna keep the collation as it is. can i make the data i get from mysql be encoded in a way where my programming language can recognise?

Comment: You would have to change the characters in the words you store to some character that is not equal to `'s'` in the default collation. IMO, I would change the collation at least on your `name` column. You don't have to change the default collation for the whole server or even the whole table. You can change a collation of a single column.